# How to write a java 8 Stream code for the following code?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "c1");
List<Integer> addList=new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(String listobj:myList) {
    String appendedobj=listobj+"%";
    List<Integer> intlist=myMethod(appendedobj,listobj);
    addList.addAll(intlist);
}


public list<Integer> mymethod(appendedobj,listobj)
{
    do something and retrurn list of integers;
}
```

I want to convert this to java 8 `Stream` code, but I'm not sure how to call `myMethod` with two arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a loop that produces for each element of the input List a List of elements to be added to the output loop. `flatMap` can be used in this case.

```
List<String> addList =
    myList.stream()
          .flatMap(listobj -> myMethod(listobj+"%",listobj).stream())
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT: I'm not sure about the types of the output `List` and the `List` returned by `mymethod()`. You mixed `List<String>` with `List<Integer>` in your code (you cannot return a `List<String>` from `mymethod` and assign it to a `List<Integer>`).